# Recognition 'for' or 'of' in the context of 'Certificate of Appreciation'?

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing text for a certificate. I see both the examples. Which one is proper? Also, is the other one incorrect?

Example of "recognition **for** valued participation"

[image: California state university]

Example of "recognition **of** valued participation"

[image: British Columbia]

---

**This is what I'm writing**

### Certificate of Appreciation

presented to

Mr. X

in recognition ***for/of*** delivering exceptional performance for the year 2014/15

---

### Certificate of Appreciation

presented to

Mr. X

as the

BEST SPORTSPERSON

in recognition ***for/of*** being the most active and versatile performer in sports

---

Or it is something like `recognition for` followed by a NOUN and `recognition of` for *to be verb* or some *verb*.

Answer (score 1):

[COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) has more entries for 'in recognition of' then 'in recognition for'.

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/recognition?source=chromex-tb-ex) has given the meaning of in recognition of as to show respect for.

Therefore, IMHO, it is better to use "in recognition of" for showing respect/admiration for someone's contribution. "In recognition for" is more useful for admiring someone's participation in something.

Say

> The certificate of appreciation is given to Mr. X in recognition for his valued **participation**.

And

> The certificate of appreciation is given to Mr. X in recognition of his valued **contribution**.

Hope this will be useful.