# How to express prizes & awards in English? Could you show me some similar examples?

Tags: expressions

I want to know: what expressions do native speakers use when they give honor, titles and/or awards to other native speakers?

Then I will follow the examples to do my homework.

I translated some of mine from Chinese into English, but I'm not confident at all

---

Prizes & awards:

2007-12

> Student Excellence of Sichuan University, 2006-2007

2006-12

> The Second Excellent Scholarship of Sichuan University, 2005-2006

2006-06

> The Third Prize at the Sichuan University Advanced Mathematics Competition (Science & Engineering)

2006-04

> The Third Prize at the Thirteenth Sichuan University General Physics Competition

2003-05

> Student Merit of Tongnan County

2001-05

> The County-level Second Prize at the Chongqing Chemistry Competition

Comment: I am sorry, Zhang Jian, we don't do proofreading on this site, and we definitely don't do translation. The text that you have written certainly does not sound natural, for example **rewards** should probably be **awards**. I recommend that you do get this text checked properly before using it.

Comment: I don't know any Chinese. Judging the English alone, the first description seems to be missing a word; maybe it should say "Recognition for Student Excellence, Sichuan University." The second one might be: Second Prize Scholarship for Student Excellence, Sichuan University. The next: Third Prize, Advanced Mathematics Competition (Science and Engineering), Sichuan University. (Note: It's not "adcanced," it's "advanced.")

Comment: Fifth is also missing a word; make it "Recognition of Student Merit, Tongnan County"

Comment: 1 Can "Student Merit" be used as a title for merit students?

Comment: 2 After reading your helpful answer, I do my homework and look up dictionary. I guess "recognition FOR" is better than "recognition OF". Am I right? @Chaim

Comment: We can help with specific questions (like this question that asks "should I use recognition OF or recognition FOR?" https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/56916/) but posts are expected to be written mostly in English and limited to one specific question about English. There is some advice for [asking questions on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/asking) in the [help].

Comment: @ColleenV If I were you, I would just ignore those Chinese characters and focus on "How to express prizes & awards in English". Do I come here for translation? Of course NOT!

Comment: @ZhangJian This question wasn't closed because it had Chinese characters.  It was closed because you asked us to check a list of English phrases for errors, which we call "proofreading" on this site.  We're trying to make a library of knowledge for future users, and we do that by focusing on **specific questions** about the English language.  Proofreading helps the original poster, but it usually doesn't help future users very much, so we close those questions as off-topic.

Comment: @snailplane There may be a bit misunderstanding between us. What I am asking is not proofreading me, but YOUR examples. Only native speakers' examples can help both me and future users. I googled the topic but didn't find useful information. (BTW google is hard to access in China.) The reason I gave my translations is just to give some clues.

Comment: @snailplane However, I'm thankful for those who closed my question, because they told me another website, https://www.italki.com/dashboard,  which I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer some of the easier ones, and hopefully that guidance can answer your question fully:

> Student Merit of Tongnan County

I would expect, most of the time, you would see this written as **Meritorious Student** – reason being that the award is going to the *student*, not to the *merit*.

---

> The Third Prize at the Thirteenth Sichuan University General Physics Competition

For a university competition, I would omit the definite article. That is, I would leave it simply as:

> Third Prize at the Thirteenth Sichuan University General Physics Competition

---

> Student Excellence of Sichuan University, 2006-2007

This one sounds incomplete. I would probably write it as:

> Award for Student Excellence at Sichuan University, 2006-2007